# What methods can be used to solve $y'=xy;y(0)=2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, alternative-proof, big-list

This is a very basic separable differential equation and can be easily solved as such:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=xy;\,y(0)=2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=xy$$
$$\frac{dy}{y}=xdx$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{y}=\int xdx$$
$$\ln|y|=\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$
$$y=Ke^\frac{x^2}{2};\,y(0)=2$$
$$2=Ke^\frac{0^2}{2}\therefore K=2$$
$$\therefore y=2e^\frac{x^2}{2}$$

I am wondering what other methods can be used to solve this problem and I intend for the answers of this question to become a compilation of these methods. I was able to solve it using Laplace Transforms and I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Power series:

Let $y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$. The initial condition imposes that $a_0=2$. Substituting this into the ODE, we obtain
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0} a_n x^{n+1}.
$$
Shifting the indices and combining into a single series, we obtain
$$
a_1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[(n+1)a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}  \right]x^n = 0.
$$
For this power series to be identically zero, each term must be zero, so we must have the following relations between the coefficients:
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_0&=2 \\
a_1&=0 \\
a_{n+2} &= \frac{a_n}{n+2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
This immediately implies that $a_n = 0$ for $n$ odd and $a_n = \frac{2}{n(n-2)(n-4)\dots(4)(2)}$ for $n$ even. If we only sum over even indices, i.e., $n = 2k$, we then have

$$
\begin{aligned}
y(x) &= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{2x^{2k}}{(2k)(2k-2)(2k-4)\dots(4)(2)} \\
&= 2\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{2^k(k)(k-1)(k-2)\dots(2)(1)} \\
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^k  \\
&= 2e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}.\quad\blacksquare
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=xy$$
Substitute $u=x^2$:
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx^2}\dfrac {dx^2}{dx}=xy$$
$$x\left (2\dfrac{dy}{du}-y\right)=0$$
$$2y'-y=0$$
The DE has constant coefficients and can be solve with an integrating factor.
$$(ye^{-u/2})'=0 $$

Answer (score 0):

Using Laplace Transforms:
$\require{cancel}$
$$y'=xy;y(0)=2$$
$$\mathscr{L}\left\{\frac{y'}{y}\right\}=\mathscr{L}\{x\}$$
$$\mathscr{L}\left\{\frac{y'}{y}\right\}=\mathscr{L}\left\{x\right\}=\frac{1}{s^2}$$
$$
\mathscr{L}\left\{\frac{y'}{y}\right\}=
\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\frac{dy}{\cancel{dx}}}{y}e^{-sx}\cancel{dx}=
\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{e^{-sx}}{y}dy=
\ln|y|e^{-sx}|_0^\infty+\int\limits_0^\infty\ln|y|se^{-sx}dx=
\ln|y(0)|+s\mathscr{L}\{\ln|y|\}$$

$$\ln|2|+s\mathscr{L}\{\ln|y|\}=\frac{1}{s^2}$$
$$\mathscr{L}\{\ln|y|\}=\frac{1}{s^3}-\frac{\ln2}{s}$$
$$\ln|y|=\frac{x^2}{2}+\ln2$$
$$y=2e^\frac{x^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could call it

1. A first-order linear differential equation.
2. An equation with an integrating factor that depends on $x$.

Comment: I am confused as to how this is an answer to my question. I was asking for different methods for solving the said first-order ODE.

Comment: Those are two different methods: 
1) use the standard formula for solving first order linear differential equations. 
2) find the integrating factor, knowing that it depends on $x$, multiply by that integrating factor, which turns the equation into an exact differential equation, and use the standard method for solving exact differential equations.